# UINavigationBar: intercept back button and back swipe gesture

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, swipe, back

I have a UINavigationBar that intercepts the back button tap that alerts the user if there are unsave changes. This is based on the solution presented in [UINavigationController and UINavigationBarDelegate.ShouldPopItem() with MonoTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413595/uinavigationcontroller-and-uinavigationbardelegate-shouldpopitem-with-monotouc) using the UINavigationBarDelegate protocol and implementing `- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item;`

Now, iOS7 has introduced the swipe-to-go-back gesture, and I'd like to intercept that as well, but can't get it to work with the solutions I've found so far, namely using `[self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(handlePopGesture:)];` and

```
- (void)handlePopGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        [self popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```

While this does pop the views, it leaves the navigation bar buttons in place, so I'm ending up with a back button that leads nowhere, as well as all other navigation button I've added to the nav bar. Any tips?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To intercept the back swipe gesture you can set `self` as the delegate of the gesture (`<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>`) and then return YES or NO from `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` based on unsaved changes:

```
// in viewDidLoad
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;

// ...
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer class]]) {

        if (self.dirty) {
            // ... alert
            return NO;
        } else
            return YES;
    } else 
        return YES;
}
```

In the alert you can ask to the user if she want to go back anyway and, in that case, pop the controller in `alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:`

Hope this is of some help.

Comment: I expected to see some problems if I changed the delegate of the gesture recognizer from its default, but I haven't seen any yet. The default delegate is an object of the class _UINavigationInteractiveTransition. I changed it to my custom subclass of UINavigationController, and it seems to be working fine.