# Declaring custom UINavigationController in xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk, uinavigationcontroller

I was wondering how can declare a custom `UINavigationController` in `Xcode 4.2` ? I have created a project which uses an [API](https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone) and needs `UINavigationController` my project does not use story boards and is viewBased application. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple to subclass a `UINavigationController` through inheritance. It's a key concept of OOP.

```
//YourClass.h
@interface YourClass : UINavigationController

@end
//YourClass.m
@implementation YourClass

@end
```

But

> This class is generally used as-is but may be subclassed in iOS 6 and later.

as written in the Overview of [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). So you may not be able to subclass a `UINavigationController` if you are supporting iOS 5 or earlier. Maybe your subclass could not work correctly. You can find a good discussion on this [stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937616/why-doesnt-apple-allow-subclassing-of-uinavigationcontroller-and-what-are-my-a).

Comment: Thank you , Should I define IBOutlet for the interface?

Comment: No, you have to create an instance for `YourClass`. `[YourClass alloc] init]` for example. But I suggest you to follow Apple doc. If you try to explain your goal maybe it's possible to find an alternative way.

Comment: I need create an image gallery for my application and I found this api :`https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone` FGallery requires an object to implement the FGalleryViewControllerDelegate protocol in order to act as the photo source for the gallery. Then just push it into the navigation controller stack as you would with any UIViewController.and since Xcode 4.2 does not create MainWindow like prior versions I need create custom UINavigationController to push and see the gallery

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean with MainWindow? Why do you need to create a UINavigationController? Do you have to see details for your gallery?  If possible share some code. Cheers.

Comment: If you download this api you will realized that ,

Answer (score 2):

I wrote my own. The key is to subclass `UIViewController` AND remember to set self.title and the icon to its first "contained" class's otherwise nothing will show up on the tabBarIcons. `UINavigationController` is only one level deep from `UIViewController`, so you can view the header and easily see what it implements, but those were the only real keys to "copy over".

In `Interface Builder`, assuming you have a nib to go along with it, make a main view that's the size of the screen (311 if you have a tabBar and Status Bar), then create a top view that's IB-outletted to be the navigation bar, and a lower view that's outletted as the container. Then do something like this:

note: I messed with the center point as I ran into many issues regarding trying to move the views without having them offset by the pixel height, even though I'm aware of relative positioning of subviews, it just didnt' work for some reason, even if only moving sideways

I'm posting this code because nobody seems to have this type of thing up. This might help someone, or more.
Stephen Johnson.

## import "CustomNavigationController.h"

```
@implementation CustomNavigationController

@synthesize backgroundImg, title1, title2, title3;


- (id) initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController*)c;
{
    
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
  

        containedControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:c, nil];
        self.title1.text = c.title; //a custom outlet for text of title, resembling the NavigationController's title basically

        [container addSubview:c.view];
        c.view.frame = container.bounds;
        back.hidden = YES; //backbutton
        c.customNavigationController = self;
        self.title = c.title;
        self.tabBarItem.image = c.tabBarItem.image;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void) dealloc;
{
    [containedControllers removeAllObjects];
    [containedControllers release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) pushViewController:(UIViewController*)v animated:(BOOL)a;
{
    float w = container.frame.size.width;
    float h = container.frame.size.height;
    [containedControllers addObject:v];
    [self.view addSubview:v.view];
   // v.view.frame = CGRectMake(w,0,w,h);
    v.view.frame = container.bounds;
    v.view.center = CGPointMake(v.view.center.x + w, v.view.center.y + container.frame.origin.y);
    v.customNavigationController = self;
    
    float time = a ? 0.31 : 0;
    
    UIViewController * lastViewController = nil;
    lastViewController = (UIViewController*)[containedControllers lastObject];
    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:time animations:^{ 
        for (UIViewController * c in containedControllers) {
            // c.view.frame = CGRectMake(c.view.frame.origin.x + w*direction, 0, w, h); 
            c.view.center = CGPointMake(c.view.center.x + w*-1, c.view.center.y);
        }
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
       
        self.title1.text = v.title;
        back.hidden = NO;        
    }];
}

- (void) popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)a;
{
    float w = container.frame.size.width;
    float h = container.frame.size.height;
    float time = a ? 0.31 : 0;
    
    float direction = 1;
    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:time animations:^{ 
        for (UIViewController * c in containedControllers) {
            // c.view.frame = CGRectMake(c.view.frame.origin.x + w*direction, 0, w, h); 
            c.view.center = CGPointMake(c.view.center.x + w*direction, c.view.center.y);
        }
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            // lastViewController = (UIViewController*)[containedControllers lastObject];
            [containedControllers removeLastObject];
        self.title1.text = ((UIViewController*)[containedControllers lastObject]).title;
        if ([containedControllers count] > 1) {
            back.hidden = NO;
        }
        else 
            back.hidden = YES;
        
    }];
}

- (IBAction) popLastVC;
{
    [self popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end
```